# Confused with Debian/Apache2 website config

Tags: debian, apache2

I find that if one browses to my website at 
    http://www.stockton.co.za 
everything works well but if I leave out the 
    [code]www[/code], namely using 
    [code]stockton.co.za[/code], I end up at the default page, same as 
    [code]devacs.za.net[/code].
I have 
    [code]stockton.co.za[/code] set as an alias in both 
    [code]/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.stockton.co.za.conf[/code] 
as well as 
    [code]/etc/apache2/site-enabled/www.stockton.co.za.conf[/code]

Please tell me what I have forgotten or skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Did you checked this?